# substring not found error

Tags: python, string, substring

I have to replace every character with the character after it by two in the alphapet. For example `g` to `i` and `a` to `c`. I always get this error while i was making the program to solve it

```
substring not found
```

Here is my code:

```
string="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
#=========this is the string on the site
alphapet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#this is the alphapet ofcourse
x=""
y=0
z=""
m=0
#that was declaring variables
#the following is a loop which would go through string
for i in string:
    #the if statement should check if i was in alphapet string
    if i in alphapet:
        if i=="y":
            string.replace(i,"a")
        elif i=="z":
            string.replace(i,"b")
         #the previous two conditions were special cases
        else:
            #the x will equal the first character as m =0 which is"g"
            x=string[m]
            #the y should equal the index of the character in alphapet this is were the error comes
            y=alphapet.index(x)
            #the z should equal the letter that comes after it by 2 in alphapet
            z=alphapet[y+2]
            #the following line should replace it
            string.replace(i,z)
            m+=1
print(string)
```

Comment: What line does it say your error is originating from?

Comment: It should be: y=alphapet.index(x)

Comment: Nothing in the code you include in your question will ever print `substring not found`.

Comment: I actually get this error when I run this. The line I have mentioned before. Maybe this depends on the python version...

Comment: Your alphabet doesn't handle whitespaces

Comment: it says it is line 15

Comment: Which line is line 15?

Comment: how can i handle the white spaces

Comment: the one with y=alphapet.index(x)

Comment: i am using python 3.5 if that helps

Comment: So you mean that a `ValueError: substring not found` is thrown. Please [edit] your question and include the full stacktrace.

Comment: sorry man i'm new to these things and i don't know what stacktrace is

Comment: and yes the error is like you said

Comment: The stacktrace is the complete error message. Some hints: 1) Your should start with using variable names that tell us their meaning. Don't use `x` or `i`, they could be anything. Use telling names like `positionOfCharInString` and `currentChar`. 2) Add some `print`s to your code to see what is going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5150763/jaw did you notice "if i in alphapet above the first case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb."
alphapet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphapet += alphapet    #This is a Trick. You can use it. 
new_string = ""
for i in s:#once edited:"for i in string:"
    if i not in alphapet:
        new_string += i
    else:
        new_string += alphapet[alphapet.index(i)+2]
print new_string
```

Comment: You need to change `for i in string` to `for i in s` or rename `s`.

Comment: that was super smart man thank you

Comment: it can also be solved by only adding "ab" at the end

Comment: Yes, in the line of five "for i in string:" should be "for i in s:"

Answer (score 1):

When running

```
x=string[m]
```

`x` will be equal to the index `m` in the `string`, including punctuation and spaces and so on.

So, when running

```
y=alphapet.index(x)
```

The program will raise an error, because there is no punctuation or spaces in your `alphapet`.

What you need to do is either modify the code to handle the punctuation, or add the punctuation to the `alphapet`.

Comment: did you notice "if i in alphapet" above the first case

Comment: @islamzidan, I haven't tested it yet, but it comes to me that `i` is different from `string[m]` because `m` is only incremented up `if i in alphapet`, while `i` is changed with each iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you increment `m` only in the else instead of each time. As soon as `i` is a character not in alphapet it's not the same as string[m] anymore. If you desindent your `m+=1`, it will solve that problem, but actually you just don't need `m` at all, since you already have `i`.

There are other problems in your code : str.replace doesn't modify a string in place (strings are immutable) but return the modified string, and you don't assign this result, so it's useless.

But even if replace() modified your string, you 'd still have a problem.

```
string = 'abcdef'
string = string.replace('a', 'c') # 'cbcdef'
string = string.replace('b', 'd') # 'cdcdef'
string = string.replace('c', 'e') # 'ededef' <- not what you want
```

So you need to construct a new separate string while iterating to do what you want.

Or you can look at the str.maketrans() method.

Answer (score 0):

See a modified version below which works.  String replacements should be saved back into the string specifically `string = string.replace(...)`.  As pointed out by others m was not incremented always in the original code.  I have used `enumerate` instead to get both string characters and indices.

```
string="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
#=========this is the string on the site
alphapet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#this is the alphapet ofcourse
x=""
y=0
z=""
m=0
#that was declaring variables

#temporarily convert the special cases
string = string.replace("y","Y")
string = string.replace("z","Z")

#the following is a loop which would go through string
#enumerate gets each string character(i) as well as its index (j)
for j,i in enumerate(string):
    if i in alphapet:
        x=string[j]
        y=alphapet.index(x)
        z=alphapet[y+2]
        string = string[:j]+string[j].replace(i,z)+string[j+1:]

#convert the special cases
string = string.replace("Y","a")
string = string.replace("Z","b")
```